# Construction of a special region

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have two regions I want to plot, as follows:

1. The base of the solid $S$ is the triangular region (in the $x$-$y$ plane) with vertices $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$, and $(0,2)$. Cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis are semicircles (assuming upward in the $z$-direction).
2. The base of the solid $S$ (in the $x$-$y$ plane) is an elliptical region with boundary curve $9x^2+4y^2=36$. Cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are isosceles right triangles (assuming upward in the $z$-direction) with hypotenuse in the base.

Is there a way in *Mathematica* to show students what these regions look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really is more a math question than a *Mathematica* question. With some amount of thought, one can derive the equations for the requested surfaces:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x - (3/2 - (3 y)/4))^2 + z^2 == (3/2 - (3 y)/4)^2,
              {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 3/2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: surface #1]

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2/4 + (Abs[y] + z)^2/9 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, 
              BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: surface #2]

Comment: Thanks. The students appreciated viewing this last night.